How to get the affected rows in Room Database using @RawQuery
Im using @RawQuery to execute my query in Room Database. But i cant find a way to get the affected rows this way.
I tried SELECT changes() as affected_rows and get the result through the cursor but it always return zero.
My code so far (I run this code after my insert, update, delete statements).
val cursor = daoUnit.query(SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT CHANGES() AS affected_rows"))
var affectedRowCount = 0
   cursor.use { innerCursor ->
        val affectedRowColumn = innerCursor.getColumnIndex("affected_rows")

        if (innerCursor.count > 0 && innerCursor.moveToFirst()){
             affectedRowCount = innerCursor.getInt(affectedRowColumn)
             Log.e("TAG", "AFFECTED ROW COUNT : $affectedRowCount")
       }
}


I believe that you will not have any luck trying to use the changes() function, perhaps due to the underlying wrapping of the code.

My code so far (I run this code after my insert, update, delete statements)

If you are using the convenience methods i.e. @Insert, @Update or @Delete then these return values that can be used to ascertain the number of changes.

As shown below, if not using the convenience methods then the number of affected rows is not obtained.

@Update and @Delete directly return the number of affected rows as an Int.
@Insert, returns either the rowid or -1 if the row was not inserted in the case of an insert that is can handle multiple rows being inserted then an array of the rowids or -1s is returned. As such the number of affected rows can be ascertained by the return.
As an example, consider the following code:-
0

First some functions in an @Dao annotated interface

:-
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
fun insert(parent: List<Parent>): LongArray

@RawQuery
fun rq(sql: SupportSQLiteQuery): Cursor

@Query("INSERT INTO parent VALUES (100,'XP1'),(null,'XP2')")
fun insertViaSQL()

@Transaction
@Query("")
fun xxx() {
    val result = insert(listOf(Parent(parent_name = "PARENT1"),Parent(parent_name = "PARENT2")))
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(rq(SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT changes() AS affected_rows")))
    var skipped=0
    var inserted = 0
    for (r in result) {
        if (r == -1L) skipped++ else inserted++
    }
    Log.d("DBINFO","Inserted ${inserted}. Skipped ${skipped}")
    rq(SimpleSQLiteQuery("INSERT INTO parent VALUES (100,'XP1'),(null,'XP2')"))
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(rq(SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT changes() AS affected_rows")))

}


And then some activity code

:-
    val parents: ArrayList<Parent> = ArrayList()
    val sql1: SupportSQLiteQuery = SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT CHANGES() AS affected_rows")
    val sql2 = SimpleSQLiteQuery("SELECT (CHANGES()) AS affected_rows")
    parents.add(Parent(parent_name = "P1"))
    parents.add(Parent(parent_name = "P2"))
    parents.add(Parent(parent_name = "P3"))
    parents.add(Parent(parent_name = "P4"))
    parents.add(Parent(1,"rowid 1 would likely already exist"))
    val result = dao.insert(parents)
    var skipped=0
    var inserted=0
    for (rslt in result) {
        if (rslt == -1L) skipped++ else inserted++
    }
    Log.d("DBINFO","Inserted ${inserted}, Skipped ${skipped}")
    insertViaSQL()
    val csr = dao.rq(sql1)
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(csr)
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(dao.rq(sql2))
    dao.xxx()


sql2 to eliminate the chance that the changes function not being within parenthesis is an issue (as will be seen it is not).
4 an attempt is made to insert 5 rows into the Parent table via the insert that inserts mutlitple objects/rows. Noting that the last has a value should result in the insert being ignored due to the UNIQUE conflict. The resultant LongArray is then used to capture the number of rows inserted and the number of rows not inserted(skipped). The results written to the log.

the expected result being 4 inserted and 1 skipped.


2 attempts are made to get the number of changes (affected rows) the returned Cursor being dumped to the log.
Finally the xxx function is invoked. This first attempting to insert two rows immediately followed by the rawquery to get the changes, the resultant cursor being dumped to the log.

the results as obtained from the insert are also written to the log (2 rows inserted 0 skipped)


the xxx function continues and attempts to insert 2 rows BUT via INSERT sql as opposed to the convenience @Insert method. This, being raw SQL, does not return any result. However, as Room has determined that no result will be returned and therefore that the raw query is not executed.
due to the raw query not being executed, the insertViaSQL function is called, this attempts the 2 inserts.
the xxx function then attempts to get the number of changes via the @RawQuery dumping the resultant Cursor to the log.

The Log includes:-
2024-09-24 15:55:19.159 D/DBINFO: Inserted 4, Skipped 1
2024-09-24 15:55:19.159 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@649c946
2024-09-24 15:55:19.160 I/System.out: 0 {
2024-09-24 15:55:19.160 I/System.out:    affected_rows=0
2024-09-24 15:55:19.160 I/System.out: }
2024-09-24 15:55:19.160 I/System.out: <<<<<
2024-09-24 15:55:19.160 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@ae23707
2024-09-24 15:55:19.161 I/System.out: 0 {
2024-09-24 15:55:19.161 I/System.out:    affected_rows=0
2024-09-24 15:55:19.161 I/System.out: }
2024-09-24 15:55:19.161 I/System.out: <<<<<
2024-09-24 15:55:19.180 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@57fc034
2024-09-24 15:55:19.180 I/System.out: 0 {
2024-09-24 15:55:19.180 I/System.out:    affected_rows=0
2024-09-24 15:55:19.180 I/System.out: }
2024-09-24 15:55:19.180 I/System.out: <<<<<
2024-09-24 15:55:19.180 D/DBINFO: Inserted 2. Skipped 0
2024-09-24 15:55:19.182 I/System.out: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@2cde5d
2024-09-24 15:55:19.182 I/System.out: 0 {
2024-09-24 15:55:19.182 I/System.out:    affected_rows=0
2024-09-24 15:55:19.182 I/System.out: }
2024-09-24 15:55:19.182 I/System.out: <<<<<

As can be seen the returned value (LongArray) from the @Insert can be used to ascertain the number of affected rows. However, at no time does the changes() built-in function return other than 0, even within the same transaction as the latter insert attempts.
Obviously @Delete and @Update are simpler as the number of affected rows is returned.
